# Filtering inside for-comprehension with futures

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I am doing something like this:

```
 (for { 
   data <- Future(getData)
   updated = makeChanges(data) if updated != data
   _ <- Future(saveUpdates(updated))
   _ <- Future(recordTransaction)
 } yield ()).recover { case e: NoSuchElementException => () }
```

When filter is not satisfied, it skips the remaining two steps (good!) by throwing an exception (not good), that I have to catch and handle at the end. Using exceptions for flow control does not feel too elegant to me though, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, aside from the obvious - wrapping all remaining lines with an if statement:

```
   _ <- if(updated != data) Future(saveUpdates(updated)) else Future.successful(())
   _ <- if(updated != data) ...
```

Comment: If you can change makeChanges to return a tuple of (changed:Boolean, updated:Data) you could pattern match on it and decide which action to take in which case. It would make it cleaner

Comment: @LouisF. not sure what you mean. I can pattern match on `updated != data`  just as easily, but not sure how to use it to make it cleaner. Replace the `if ... else ..` in the last snipped with `match ... case`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can avoid the exception for the flow control using for comprehension in that way, you could use a nested expression instead of the filter and handle the condition manually giving scala the return type it needs in case the condition is not satisfied:

```
for {
  data <- Future(data)
  updated = makeChanges(data)
  res = {
    if (updated != data) Future.successful(())
    else for {
      _ <- Future(saveUpdates(updated))
      _ <- Future(recordTransaction)
    } yield ()
  }
} yield res
```

But for this example I'd go the simple way and drop the for comprehension which results in more readable code (probably your real use case is more complex though):

```
Future(data).flatMap(d => {
  val updated = makeChanges(d)
  if(updated == d) Future.successful(())
  else Future(saveUpdates(updated)).map(_ => recordTransaction)
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I am not a big fan of for-comprehensions myself, but in this particular case, I don't think your suggestion  is "more readable" at all :( If there is anything I dislike more than overuse of for-comprehensions, it's excessive nesting.